# Decomposing Toeplitz Matrix with "Half" Fourier Transform.

Tags: matrices, diagonalization, block-matrices, toeplitz-matrices

In a previous question [1] the author claims that

> We can write a complex toeplitz matrix $A$ of size $M \times M$ as $$A
> = F^H_2 D F_2$$ Where $D$ is a diagonal matrix and $F_2$ contains the first $M$ columns of a $2M \times 2M$ DFT matrix.

**Question 1.**  Why is this possible?

**Question 2.** Are there any efficient way to find $D$?

[1] [Factorization of a Toeplitz-block Toeplitz matrix $A$ (Toeplitz Matrix with Toeplitz Blocks) as a product $A = Q^H D \, Q$ using a diagonal matrix $D$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2827887/factorization-of-a-toeplitz-block-toeplitz-matrix-a-toeplitz-matrix-with-toep)

Comment: If your matrix $A$ has real only entries, then it's full Fourier transform is redundant by a factor of 2 since the Fourier transform on a real function is "Hermitian". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_function

Comment: Рььб ыщккн Ш вшв тще ыуу ерфе Ф цфы сщьздуч сфдгувю

Comment: Oops sorry did not see $A_{ij}\in \mathbb C$, I thought $A_{ij}\in \mathbb R$

Comment: Why would you want to use a double size DFT matrix in the first place?

Comment: @matreadler I think it is more a necessity than a want. By using the $n \times 2n$ DFT we get a diagonal form for our Toeplitz matrix. This does not seem to be possible with the $n \times n$ DFT.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be a [Toeplitz matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix). It is then possible to construct matrices $B$ and $M$ so $M$ is a [Circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix): 
$$M = 
\begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\ 
B & A
\end{pmatrix}
$$
This requires us to choose $B$ in a particular way (see [0] for details). Since $M$ is a Circulant matrix it can be [decomposed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix#Other_properties) as follows: 
$$
 \begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\ 
B & A
\end{pmatrix}
=  
\begin{pmatrix}
F_{1,1} & F_{1,2} \\ 
F_{2,1} & F_{2,2}
\end{pmatrix}^H\begin{pmatrix}D_1 & 0 \\ 0& D_2 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
F_{1,1} & F_{1,2} \\ 
F_{2,1} & F_{2,2}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
By [block matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_multiplication) we can then get the wanted equation:
$$
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}F_{1,1} \\ F_{2,1} \end{pmatrix} ^H 
\begin{pmatrix}D_1 & 0 \\ 0 & D_2 \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}F_{1,1} \\ F_{2,1} \end{pmatrix}
=F_2^H \begin{pmatrix}D_1 & 0 \\ 0 & D_2 \end{pmatrix} F_2
$$

The diagonal matrices $D_1$ and $D_2$ can be efficiently computed using the FFT since $M$ is circulant [0].

[0] http://www.netlib.org/utk/people/JackDongarra/etemplates/node384.html