# Question related to diagonalization of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Suppose we are given that A=\begin{bmatrix}4&11&20&30\\ 0&4&11&20\\ 0&0&4&11\\ 0&0&0&4\end{bmatrix}
I need to show that if F is a Fourier matrix then
$$F^{-1}AF=D$$ where D is a diagonal matrix containing eigen values of A.
I am doubtful before starting solving this problem. Clearly the matrix A is not diagonalizable.  Is this scenario possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Circulant** matrices are ensured to be diagonalizable by the Fourier matrix.

The matrix you have is not **circulant**, but it is **Toeplitz**.

You can follow this answer for how to construct a circulant matrix from a Toeplitz one.

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3415198/213607

Depending on what you want to do, this might help you.